# Restricting scalars from complex to real in explicit matrix computation

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Hi I'm reviewing Linear Algebra for exams and the following question came up.

Let the matrix

$\pmatrix{1+i & 3 \\ 2+i & 2-i}$

represent a linear map over the complex numbers.
Find a real 4x4 matrix that represents that linear map restricting the scalars to the real numbers.

I chose the bases {(1,0),(0,1)} of C^2 over C and {1,i} of C over R, so that {(1,0),(0,1),(i,0),(0,i)} is a basis of C^2 over R.
I'm not sure if what I did next is correct.

I took the vectors of the last basis and wrote their images under the map. Then I identified those basis vectors with the canonical basis of R^4. I obtained the following matrix:

$\pmatrix{1 & 3 & -1 & 0 \\ 2 & 2 & -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\ 1 & -1 & 2 & 2}$.

Is it correct?

Comment: I would advise ordering your last basis as $\{(1,0), (i,0), (0,1), (0,i)\}$. It is easier to follow when you keep the real and imaginary parts of the same number together instead of separating them.

Comment: Other than that (which is only a suggestion), it looks fine.